# C++ "<<" operator overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've got this class:

```
// in Platform.h
class Platform
{
private:
    float y;
    float xi;
    float xf;
public:
    Platform(float y, float xi, float xf);
    virtual ~Platform(void);
    float getxi();
    float getxf();
};
```

And I want to be able to do this:

```
Platform* p = new Platform(1.0,2.0,3.0);
cout << p; // should it be *p?
```

I tried overloading the "<<" operator, like this:

```
// in Platform.cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Platform* p ) 
{
    out << "Platform: xi=" << p->getxi() << ", xf=" << p->getxf() << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

But this just prints a memory address (of course, because `p` is a pointer...).
I'm quite sure that the above function isn't being called at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes do a *p:

```
so cout << *p ;
```

And the conventional operator is...

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Platform& p) { }
```

You also need to export this in the header file so it is visible outside. Add:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Platform* p ) ;
```

To Platform.h

Comment: *"Otherwise the template searches for and finds the pointer print function."* No, his overload should be called instead. I'm guessing it wasn't visable from where he was calling from as Yakk said.

Comment: Should I add `#include "Platform.cpp"` in the file that calls `cout << *p` ?

Comment: No, add a "friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Platform* p ) ; " to Platform.hpp

Comment: @DavidMokonBond: Why would you want this to be a `friend` if it only uses `public` functions?

Comment: Reasonable point, but I copied that from some of my code and I think its pretty standard for that having access to private data. Really depends though of course... If you have a nice system where you have gettters for everything you need sure...

Answer (score 2):

The overload declaration needs to be visible from where you use it.  Change it to `Platform const&` and use `*p` while you are at it, because that is the conventional way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this works in g++ 4.7.2 but perhaps it depends on the compiler. You can do:

```
// in Platform.cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Platform& p ) 
{
    out << "Platform: xi=" << p.getxi() << ", xf=" << p.getxf() << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

And print using indirection (`*p`)